# Keeping scale consistency with SNIC algorithm in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-segmentation

This is more of a theoretical question about scale when using the SNIC algorithm in GEE.

I'm doing an object-based classification in GEE using the SNIC algorithm and then random forest to classify the SNIC clusters. My understanding is that the SNIC results need to be reprojected (before any other data manipulation) in order to keep scale consistency -- meaning avoiding the issue of displaying different cluster results when changing the zoom levels in the code editor map window.

I have also seen in other forum/questions that an alternative to using the .reproject() function would be to set the scale when exporting the results. The problem is that I've tested both options and the results look a bit different.

Here is an example of what I did.

Option 1) using .reproject()

```
var naipCol = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NAIP/DOQQ')
                  .filterBounds(geometry) // study region
                  .filterDate('2014-01-01', '2014-12-31');

// get image projection
var b1prj = naipCol.first().projection()

// mosaic images and set projection
var NAIP = naipCol.mosaic().setDefaultProjection(b1prj, null, 1)

// SNIC
var segmentation = function(image){
  var segments = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC({
    image: image,
    size:3,
    compactness: 1,
    connectivity: 8
    });
  return segments;
};

var snic = segmentation(NAIP);

var snicRepj = snic.reproject({crs: snic.projection(), scale: 1})

// Random Forest Classification
var predBands = snicRepj.bandNames();

var RFmodel = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(1000).train(training, 'ID_classes', predBands);

var RFclassified = snicRepj.select(predBands).classify(RFmodel);


// Export Results
```

Option 2) setting scale when exporting results at the end:

```
var naipCol = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NAIP/DOQQ')
                  .filterBounds(geometry) // study region
                  .filterDate('2014-01-01', '2014-12-31');

// get image projection
var b1prj = naipCol.first().projection()

// mosaic images and set projection
var NAIP = naipCol.mosaic().setDefaultProjection(b1prj, null, 1)

// SNIC
var segmentation = function(image){
  var segments = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC({
    image: image,
    size:3,
    compactness: 1,
    connectivity: 8
    });
  return segments;
};

var snic = segmentation(NAIP);

var snicPrj = snic.setDefaultProjection(b1prj, null, 1) //original 1-meter resolution

// Random Forest Classification
var predBands = snicPrj.bandNames();

var RFmodel = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(1000).train(training, 'ID_classes', predBands);

var RFclassified = snicPrj.select(predBands).classify(RFmodel);

// Export Results

Export.image.toAsset({
                    image:  RFclassified,
                    description: "LC_classification", 
                    region: geometry, //study region
                    scale: 1,  // original NAIP resolution
                    maxPixels: 1e13
})
```

My main questions are:

1. Should these two options (e.g. using .reproject() and setting the scale when exporting results) lead to the same classification result? If yes, any idea of why my results look different?
2. Would .setDefaultProjection() work as an alternative to .reproject() to keep scale consistency on the SNIC results?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking *practical* questions, and only One question per Question. Questions with bullet lists of questions are easy prey to the `Close` button. Please [Edit] your Question to improve practicality and focus.

Comment: It's possible that in option 1 the data are reprojected/resampled twice (once for `reproject()` call and again at export call) which could give you a different result than option 2, which is only a single reproject/resample. You shouldn't be calling `reproject` except to preview the result in the Code Editor Map. Once you're satisfied with the cluster results, remove the reproject and let the export function handle it - you'll get the most consistent result by using the `crsTransform` and `crs` params as defined in e.g., `naipCol.first().projection()`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `proj = ee.Projection('EPSG:4326').atScale(1)`.  What should be identical is:
(a) `setDefaultProjection(proj)` followed by `Export`
(b) `Export` with the proj explicitly specified.

I think `reproject(proj)` on exactly the same image immediately prior to `Export` should give you the same result.

However, in your example, it's not obvious that you have only one `proj` and you haven't specified it everywhere, for example in [Export.image.toAsset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/export-image-toasset).  I'd suggest standardizing your projection and using that at export.